# Facing segmentation fault while using toupper()

Tags: c, gcc, segmentation-fault, getchar, toupper

The following method causes an error:

```
BOOL should_begin(void) {
    char yn;
    do {
        printf("Continue? [Y/N] ");
        yn = getchar();
        printf("\n");
        yn = toupper(yn);
        if (yn == 'N') {
            return FALSE;
        }
    } while (yn != 'Y');
    return TRUE;
}
```

The code executes normally until `toupper()` is reached, at which point there is a segmentation fault. I've seen questions like this where `toupper()` was called on part of a string, but it was only when someone tried to modify a literal.

So what gives? `char yn` shouldn't be read only, right? It's just a `char`, a single byte of data, I'm not reading a whole string, am I?

---

**EDIT**:

This is my `main()` function.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    /* just some printf()s with instructions */

    if (!should_begin()) {
        return 0;
    }

    /* then continue with rest of the program */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is pretty much the full code. Nothing else but some #include's and #define's.

Comment: I hope you did not miss `#include <ctype.h>`, did you?

Comment: No. I included <ctype.h>.

Comment: How do you know it crashes at toupper() and not at any of the code in `/* then continue with rest of the program */` ? It's anyway not likely the error is in the code already posted here, so please post a *complete* example that shows this crash.

Comment: @nos. I placed printf()s before and after toupper(), and only the one before printed.

Comment: Change the type of `yn` to `int` (prefereably) or (atleast) to `unsigned char`

Comment: May I suggest you to use a debugger to ensure that really is `toupper` failing.

Comment: `ToUpper()` was not the line that was failing. The segfault happened elsewhere in this program. This question should be closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`getchar()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar) returns `int`. Some of the return values *may not* fit into a `char`.

Change `yn` to `int yn`.

Then, from the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/toupper) for `toupper()`

> `int toupper(int c);`
>
> If `c` is not an unsigned char value, or `EOF`, the behavior of these functions is undefined.

So, you need to check for `EOF` before passing `yn` to `toupper()`.

FWIW, the `toupper()` is prototyped in `ctype.h`, you have to `#include` the same.

Comment: You got it right. If an implementation uses an array of `1 << CHAR_BITS` to store char flags and index `c` blindly, this can cause segmentation fault. And specs have no issues with that and it is programmers responsibility.

Comment: Thanks @MohitJain sir for the added explanation. :-)

Comment: Alternative fix: `int input = getchar(); if(input == EOF) { error_handling(); } yn = (unsigned char)input;`